# Different error functions in LOOCV

Tags: cross-validation

Suppose I'm performing a regression with a tuning parameter.

I can perform LOOCV to determine the 'optimal' value of this parameter.

Currently, I'm getting different values depending on whether I use the RMSE or the MSE. However, since $\sqrt{x}$ is a strictly increasing function, I would expect the parameter that minimises the MSE and RMSE to be the same. Is this the case? I just want to make sure what I'm seeing isn't expected behaviour before I explore further.

Comment: What parameter are you optimizing, and how, in detail, is the optimization being performed, to include the criteria for terminating the optimization?

Comment: Are you getting the same performance from those two different parameters? That is, if you use parameter $\lambda_{MSE}$ to minimize $MSE$ and parameter $\lambda_{RMSE}$ to minimize $RMSE$, do you get equal $MSE$ from the two models?